# How do I find σ in this normally distributed random variable?

Tags: probability

X is a normally distributed random variable with μ = 5. If P (X>9) = 0.2. What is σ?

I know that $$Z = \frac {X - μ}{σ} $$

Is it correct if I rearrange the equation to solve for σ?

$$ σ = \frac {X - μ}{Z} $$

The problem is that I'm not given Z. I know that there's has to be something to do with P (X>9) = 0.2

I'm just puzzled and stuck in this part.

The answer should be σ ≈ 4.76

Comment: You can use $P[X>9] = P\left[\underbrace{\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}}_{Z}>\underbrace{\frac{9-\mu}{\sigma}}_{z}\right]$.  I am guessing you then have a book with a lookup table, or you have some way of computing the $Q$ or inverse $Q$ function [being the Gaussian tail function].

Comment: Think of it this way: "A rectangle is placed with it's geometric centroid at $x = 5$. The area of this rectangle is $1$, and the area right of $x = 9$ is $0.2$." This should allow you to get the bounds of the distribution, which makes the rest fairly easy.

Comment: So I must set up P(X>9) = P (x−μ/σ). Then 0.2 = P (x−μ/σ) but I don't know what is x or σ. I just think know that μ = 5.

Comment: No.  Somehow your $X$ turned into an $x$ (there is no $x$ in this problem). And you neglected parentheses.

Comment: Your edit in the quesiton is good, but your above comment writes $P(x-\mu/\sigma)$ which does not make sense (you can only take probabilities of events), you mean $P[(X-\mu)/\sigma > (9-\mu)/\sigma]$. Surely you have some way of evaluating things like $P[Z> 0.65]$ or $P[Z>3.4]$, or finding the $z$ such that $P[Z>z]=.12$, for $Z$ a zero-mean unit variance Gaussian?

Comment: @Michael. So, $$P(X>9) = P \bigg[ \frac {X - σ}{σ} > \frac {9-μ}{σ} \bigg]$$ Then I should think of P(X>9) = 0.2 and σ = 5. Thus, $$ 0.2 = P \bigg[ \frac {X - 5}{σ} > \frac {9-5}{σ} \bigg]$$ This should give me, $$ 0.2 = P \bigg[ \frac {X - 5}{σ} > \frac {4}{σ} \bigg]$$ but I just don't know how to narrow down this expression to find σ ≈ 4.76. I can think of cross-multiplying the $$P \bigg[ \frac {X - 5}{σ} > \frac {4}{σ} \bigg]$$ to get $$P \bigg[ \frac{4σ}{(X-5)σ} \bigg] = 0.2$$ but I know this might be wrong. I'm trying to find a way to isolate and solve for σ to get σ ≈ 4.76.

Comment: There are some minor typos in your above comment (i.e., you mean $\mu=5$, not $\sigma=5$) but I see what you mean. Can you answer me on this question?  "Do you have a way to compute things like $P[Z>0.65]$ or $P[Z>3.4]$ or finding the $z$ such that $P[Z>z]=.12$"?

Comment: We use a phi table @Michael

Comment: Great.  Now, that table is defined for Gaussian 0-mean, unit variance random variables $Z$, is it not?

Comment: The 10-minute pauses in the conversation are excruciating.  I think I need to go.

Comment: Sorry for the 10 minute wait @Michael. I just think that the standard deviation for any P(Z=0) would be 0.5 right?

Comment: Usually a $\phi$ table gives values for the function $\phi(z) = P[Z\leq z]$, where $Z$ is a "standard normal" or "zero-mean-unit-variance" Gaussian. From this you can get $P[Z>z]$ via $P[Z > z] = 1-P[Z\leq z]$. "zero-mean-unit-variance" means $\mu=0$ and $\sigma^2=1$, that is, $E[Z]=0, Var(Z)=1$.

Comment: I kind of figured it out already @Michael thanks for your help!

Comment: The "kind of" is not reassuring.  Note that the point of manipulating the equation to get an expression "$\frac{X-5}{\sigma}$" is to substitute "$Z$" for this expression. I had hoped that was evident from the underbrace of my very first comment.

Comment: Also your comment "I just think that the standard deviation for any $P[Z=0]$ would be 0.5" does not make any sense: (i) Standard deviations apply to random variables, not probabilities, (ii) Since $Z$ is a continuous random variable, we have $P[Z=0]=0$.  So your comment is like saying "my age is green and my height is car."

Answer (score 0):

You are given
$$.2 = P(X > 9) = P\left(\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma} > \frac{9-5}{\sigma} = \frac{4}{\sigma}\right) = P(Z > 4/\sigma).$$
However, from printed tables of the standard normal CDF, you can find $c$ such
$P(Z > c) = .2$ is $c \approx .84$

So $4/\sigma = .84$ and $\sigma = 4/.84 = 4.76.$ (If you were using software
instead of tables, you could get $c = 0.4816,$ but that wouldn't make much
difference in the final answer.)

I am totally aware that essentially this method was presented in Comments of @Michael, but sometimes it is easy to get confused by "Answers" in Comment format. So I hope this way of writing it out is of help to you.